Does Excel recalculate cells flagged as Dirty that are not on the ActiveSheet?
I have an Excel add-in (XLAM) running in Excel 365 (version 2308) that has a core function that crawls an ActiveWorkbook looking for particular UDFs, flagging them as Dirty and then (when all Worksheets have been scanned and flagged) updates some data that those UDFs are referring to. All of this happens with Calculation set programmatically to Manual, and then it is flipped back to Automatic when the updating code is finished.
I expect the Dirty-flagged cells on ALL sheets to recalculate when the add-in flips Calculation back to Automatic, but (at least on a calculation with several large-ish sheets) it only seems to recalculate the ActiveSheet and not all sheets?
I could get the add-in to force full Workbook recalculation when it exits, but I do not want to do this because some of the calculations are very large and take ages to recalculate, and there is no point doing so if none of the Dirty cells have actually changed in value i.e. I am trying to only recalculate the necessary cells (which sometimes, if all inputs have changed, will mean the whole Workbook).
Update:
ChatGPT suggests (but this is clearly not based on much of a corpus of data!) that the Range.Dirty flags can only exist on a single Worksheet at a time, so as soon as you move to another sheet, the flags get cleared from previous sheets. This does not quite explain the behaviour I am seeing though, as it is consistently the ActiveSheet that correctly recalculates as soon as I slip calculation to Automatic, and all other sheets just stay showing what they used to until I either manually enter the cells and hit Enter, or force a full recalc.
Update 2 - added real code
Here is the code, with clutter removed, to make sure I am not making any silly mistakes:
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets                ' Loop through each worksheet (ignore charts etc.)
    formatable = can_edit_format(ws)
    ' Search for all cells on the sheet that contain the relevant formula
    Application.StatusBar = "Scanning sheet: '" & ws.Name & "' for refStrings."
    Set GSDcells = Nothing
    cell_values = ws.UsedRange.Value2: cell_formulae = ws.UsedRange.formula: rcount = UBound(cell_values, 1): ccount = UBound(cell_values, 2)
    For rnum = 1 To rcount
        For cnum = 1 To ccount
            If Left(cell_formulae(rnum, cnum), 1) <> "=" Then
            ElseIf InStr(1, LCase(cell_formulae(rnum, cnum)), LCase(func_name)) > 0 Then
                cell_formula = cell_formulae(rnum, cnum)
                If IsError(cell_values(rnum, cnum)) Then             ' Catch the #N/A cases that cause the line below to fail
                ElseIf is_valid_func(cell_formula) Then
                    append_to_range GSDcells, ws.cells(rnum, cnum)
                Else
                    ' If cell formula is not valid, mark it in a way that is no relevant
                End If
            End If
SkipCell:
        Next cnum
    Next rnum
    If Not GSDcells Is Nothing Then
        GSDcells.Dirty
        If formatable Then GSDcells.Font.Color = GSD_Font_Colour ' Format all found cells GREEN
    End If
SkipSht:
Next ws

...

Public Sub append_to_range(range_to_extend As Range, cell_item As Range)
' Appends cell_item to range_to_extend
    If range_to_extend Is Nothing Then
        Set range_to_extend = cell_item
    Else
        Set range_to_extend = Union(range_to_extend, cell_item)
    End If
End Sub

The SkipCell and SkipSht labels are Resume points for error handling, but are not relevant for this question, I don't believe, because the actions I expect to happen after the call to append_to_range are successfully happening, so I am not simply skipping over target cells unexpectedly. The weird way I am looping through the sheets is to avoid Excel crashing if UsedRange is large - looping in the way above is much more robust to large sheets.

Setting Calculation to Automatic does not trigger the Calculate event. Probably, there were changes in the active sheet, to calculate it. You should also add wb.Calculate, where wb is the workbook object you need to calculate... Then, why using Dirty? I mean, you can use rng.Calculate, instead of Dirty, if you can identify the ranges where the respective UDFs reference...

I use .Dirty because the data has not changed at the point in time I identify the Range objects in question. I mark them all as Dirty as I go, also collecting information about whether any new data from external sources is required. After the external data is retrieved, I need all the affected Range objects to recalculate at that point.
I'll try your suggestion of using wb.Calculate and see if that gives the expected behaviour.

Actually, there is no wb.Calculate method - did you mean Application.Calculate?

Yes, you are right. I forgot about it... I remember I did it, iterating between its all sheets. Something as: Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet Set wb = ActiveWorkbook For Each ws In wb.Worksheets: ws.Calculate: Next ws...

I tried that too, but it still only recalculates the ActiveSheet. Is it possible that the .Dirty flag can only persist on a single sheet at a time?
If so, I may have to run my loop again to mark each sheet's Ranges as Dirty after I have updated the data sources... slower, but probably acceptable.

I do not think it recalculates only the active sheet. Except the case of using a wrong code (unfortunately, you do not show it...) not fully qualifying the ranges you handle... And VBA treats them as being part of he active sheet (the last processed one...).
